# How do we go about roles and ownership based authentication in flask-login?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-login

I need to segregate dashboards for different user roles, how can we do it in flask-login, a user can have a single role assigned to it.
And each user of the role will be assigned to a different entity and it needs to access only that.

Comment: And each user of the role will be assigned to a different entity and it needs to access only that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just define a many-to-many relationship between user and roles classes. Then using a decorator, check `if role in user.roles`